# Showing that $m_f = m_g$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Hello fellow Mathematics enthusiasts, I have a question regarding the equivalence of measures from Terry Tao's *An Epsilon of Room* book.

Let $m$ be $\sigma-$finite. Given two functions $f,g :X \to [0,\infty]$, show that $m_f=m_g$ if and only if $f(x)=g(x)$ for $m-$almost every $x$. (Hint: as usual, first do the case when $m$ is finite. The key point is that if $f$ and $g$ are not equal $m-$almost everywhere, then either $f>g$ or $f<g$ on a set of positive measure).

Give a counterexample to show that this uniqueness statement can fail if $m$ is not $\sigma-$finite.

Here is my attempt:

$(\Rightarrow)$

Since $f$ and $g$ are measurable, then we have the formulas

$m_f(E) = \int_X 1_Ef d\mu$ and $m_g(E) = \int_X 1_Eg d\mu$ for some set $E \in X$.

Since $m_f = m_g$ by assumption, then we have the equality of the integrals above. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then we can write

$|m_f(E)-m_g(E)|< \epsilon$ and thus $f(x)=g(x)$ for $m-$almost every $x$.

As for the other direction, I am unsure how to continue or whether my above argument is legitimate or not since I do not think I used the hint provided. As for the counterexample at the end, I am also confused about how to proceed.

Could somebody please assist me with this problem?

Thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to the free online version of the text, which is the one I am using:
http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/gsm-117-tao3-epsilon1.pdf

Comment: I asked a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2799884/importance-of-sigma-finiteness-for-uniqueness-of-measure-dm-f-f-dm) about the necessity of the $\sigma$-finiteness assumption.  My question includes a proof of the problem you ask about.