# Importance of $\sigma$-finiteness for Uniqueness of Measure $dm_f = f dm$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

#### Background

Given a measure $m : X \rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ and a measurable function $f : X \rightarrow [0,+\infty]$, we can define a new measure by integrating $f$ as below:

$$
m_f(E) = \int_E f \, dm
$$

I'm not aware of a name for $m_f$, hence the awkward title.  My question arises from Exercise #1.2.2 of Tao, *"Epsilon of Room, Vol. I"*, which states the following:

> **EOR #1.2.2:** Let $m$ be $\sigma$-finite.  Given two functions $f,g : X \rightarrow [0,+\infty]$, show that $m_f = m_g$ if and only if $f = g$ for $m$-almost every $x$.  Give and example to show that this uniqueness statement can fail if $m$ is not $\sigma$-finite.

I am trying to better understand the importance of the $\sigma$-finiteness condition.  For reference, here is my proof of the statement.

#### Proof

The $\impliedby$ direction is easy and true even when $X$ is not $\sigma$-finite.  For the $\implies$ direction, we prove the contrapositive.

Let $\mu(X) < +\infty$ and suppose $f$ is not almost-everywhere equal to $g$, that is, $f \neq g$ on a set $E$ of positive but possibly infinite measure.

1. Without loss of generality, we can take $f > g$ on $E$ since the sets $E \cap 1_{f > g}$ and $E \cap 1_{f < g}$ cannot both be null.  This condition prevents $g$ from being infinite on $E$.
2. Moreover, we may assume $\mu(E) < +\infty$ is finite because each infinite-measure set in a sigma-finite space necessarily has a subset of positive measure.  This ensures $m_g(E) < +\infty$.
3. Then, $m_f(E) = \int_E f \, dm > \int_E g \, dm  = m_g(E)$, where it is possible for $m_f(E) = +\infty$ but $m_g(E)$ must be finite.

#### Counterexample

Let $X = \{ a \}$ be a singleton set and $\mu : \{ \emptyset, X \} \rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ be the measure which assigns $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ and $\mu(X) = +\infty$.  Clearly $X$ is not $\sigma$-finite.  Let $f(a) = 1$ and $g(a) = 2$.  Then $m_f(X) = m_g(X) = +\infty$, but $f \neq g$.

#### Questions

1. **What is stopping uniqueness from being true when $X$ is not $\sigma$-finite?**  Like the counterexample suggests, we run into problems when $f$ and $g$ only disagree on sets of infinite measure, because then it is possible that $m_f(E) = m_g(E) = +\infty$.  Is this the only problematic case?
2. **For which classes of functions is $m_f$ unique even when $X$ is not $\sigma$-finite?**  What if we restrict $g$ to be integrable?  Then for any $E$, we have $m_g(E) < \int_X g dm < +\infty$.  This could be too strong an assumption though since integrable functions have $\sigma$-finite support.